# Rest API: Get Calls: Should return 404 or something else when request have query parameters which are not present in DB

Tags: api, rest, error-code

**Example:** GET: {{url}}/path?query1=val1&query2=val2

Now, val1 & val2 are query parameters and there is no combination available in Database with these 2 parameters. So in that case what should API returns?

**My Opinion:**

- If values passed in Query parameters don't find any matching record in DB it should return "204 - No Content" or "404 - Not Found".

  - If API is expected to always return data, then it should return 404 when no data matches the query parameters value.
  - If API is expected to return either Null/Data then it should return 204 (Typical Search Case).

**Dev Opinion:**

- If the path parameters are not matching then only return 404 else if the Query parameters are not matching then it should return 204

Need your thoughts, please suggest....

DB

| id | Frist Name | Last Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mukesh | Suthar | Business User |
| 2 | Vijay | Kumar | Franchise User |

API: {{url}}/find?FirstName=Mukesh&LastName=Kumar

Response: Returning 204 - No Content (Which is okay for a simple search when a record can be present or not)

Expected: Should Return "404 - Not Found" as the requested user is not found (Which is required to throw an error as on the basis of the query parameters it returns a specific value which is required for further processing.)

Comment: What data format is your API returning? It often makes more sense to just respond with a 200 OK (the request itself did not have any syntactical errors here), and then an empty data set in the body (for example when you are returning JSON.) It can be much easier for the _users_ of your API, to simply process an empty data set, rather than having to deal with HTTP status codes on top of everything else.

Comment: Especially for a `find` operation you want to perform a query on that is not able to return useful data is just an edge-case of the same operation returning data that matches the search criteria. As such, returning a 200 OK response with a content that states that no search results were obtainable for the given query is a fine approach. People though usually mingle their business concerns 1:1 with the ones of the transport layer and therefore also end up in a mix of interpretation approaches

Comment: Actual Scenario:
This API is used for a button, and when the user clicks on the button it redirects the user to some link which is returned in the API response.
Now, this link is fetched from an environment property table which is used by various application interfaces to fetch the data (for example Link, Text, Encrypted strings, etc).

Comment: The problem is if the user clicks on the button and for any reason, if that property is removed then this API will not return any data but if there is no error then on the button click there will be no error. So we need some kind of error.